# Golang net.ListenTCP Structure

Tags: tcp, go

The definition for the Golang function net.ListenTCP is:

```
func ListenTCP(net string, laddr *TCPAddr)
```

So it takes a string which is the type / version of TCP being used, and then a TCPAddr struct, which defines things like IP address to bind to, port to use etc.

However, I often see this function used like this:

```
net.ListenTCP("tcp", ":8080")
```

If the second parameter is looking for a TCPAddr struct / object, why does passing it a string work?

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing `net.ListenTCP` with [`net.Listen`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listen).

```
func ListenTCP(net string, laddr *TCPAddr) (*TCPListener, error)
```

vs

```
func Listen(net, laddr string) (Listener, error)
```